# OpenTTD: How do I allow for multiple trains on a track?

Tags: openttd

I have a train track loop on a map with two trains on it. Orders for both trains are identical, and they move clockwise around the loop:

```
station A -> waypoint A -> station B -> waypoint B -> ...
```

However one of the two trains is always parked at the depot. When the currently active train enters the depot for maintenance the other takes off.

What changes do I need to make such that I can have more than one train operating on the loop simultaneously?

Comment: None of two answers really answer the questions -- they are just 'RTFM" messages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add signals. Depots have built in signals, but stations and waypoints *do not*.

Answer (score 10):

As @Williham said you need signals.

There are several different kinds of signals that can be used to construct very advanced track systems. That's one of the main points that make OpenTTD so great.

In your case you need one-way signals but I highly recommend that you do some reading about the other signals as well:

- Block signals
- Pre signals
- Path signals

An excellent overview is given at http://wiki.openttd.org/Signals

Comment: Thanks for the link- the differences seem subtle but important.